# Delay on first RPC (GWT and Guice) , MVP-Pattern

Tags: gwt, mvp, guice, dispatcher, code-injection

I am using Guice (MVP) on GWT. The thing I want to know more about that is why first RPC gets a little time more. It seems for Guice-injection there is 30 sec timeout.

If next RPC acts in 30 sec, there is no delay, but if the RPC arrive after 30 sec, we have a delay again.

Comment: Is this running on app engine?